# Luac: read version 1280.1; expected at most 80.1

Tags: lua, luac

I try to load a `.lc` file that I compiled with `luac` beforehand:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

and

```
luac -o helloworld.lc helloworld.lua
```

in order to get the compilation. However, as I am importing that module I am getting:

```
\lua\ai\helloworld.lc too new: read version 1280.1; expected at most 80.1
```

This is my `luac -v`

```
E:\lua\lua-5.0.3\bin>luac -v
Lua 5.0.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2006 Tecgraf, PUC-Rio
```

The game I am modding is actually using Lua 5.0 which is why I don't really understand why I am seeing this error..

Comment: Does `luac -v -l -p helloworld.lc` work?

Comment: @lhf Hmm, I am not sure what exactly should change if I do that?

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether the Lua embeded into your app might be a different version.

Comment: @lhf If I run `luac -v` I am getting `5.0.3` .. the [documentation of the game](http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/Lua) says: "*SupCom uses a slightly modified version of Lua 5.0.*" - not sure what "*slightly*" means but I am slowly getting the impression that it should actually say "*extensively*" modified ..